# Unable to hear the sound effect in cocos2dx

Tags: c++, audio, cocos2d-x

I have the following code and the problem is that the battle.mp3 music plays normally however, the bang.mp3 sound effect does not play. Any ideas?

```
bool GameLayer::init(int level)
{
    if (!Layer::init())
        return false;

SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playBackgroundMusic("battle.mp3", true);
SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->setEffectsVolume(1.5);
SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->preloadEffect("bang.mp3");
```

I tried to play the following sound effect when the enemy character is damaged, but unable to hear any sound.

```
int soundID = SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playEffect("bang.mp3");
```

Comment: On which platform you're trying to run ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()` instead of `SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()` because `sharedEngine()` is deprecated now.

For Sound Effects, `.mp3` only supports on iOS

**Sound Effects**

```
|    Platform     |   supported sound effects formats   |
|-----------------|:-----------------------------------:|
| Android Supports|         .ogg , .wav format.         |
| iOS             |          .mp3, .wav, .caf           |   
| Windows Desktop |         .mid and .wav only          |
```

Comment: mp3 works on android, aac works on ios and most android devices as well.

Comment: Is it works for `SoundEffects` in cocos2d-x. I've not tested `.mp3` in cocos2d-x yet but I've [link](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Audio#Sound-Effects) for same of cocos2d-x wiki

Comment: This wiki is outdated AF.

Comment: Thank you Abhishek Aryan, the problem was that I have been using mp3 as the sound effect. Solved by using Wav.